# Using Azure as my host, how can I scan user-uploaded files for viruses and malware?

Tags: .net, azure, antivirus, mcafee

I am running a cloud-based .NET (C#) app in Azure and have a requirement for scanning all files uploaded by users for viruses and malware.

I took a look at both Azure Anti-malware and McAfee Endpoint Protection for Azure but it wasn't immediately clear if these support file upload scanning before the files are committed to storage. Ideally, any suspicious file would be nuked before getting stored as opposed to the file being stored and later scanned.

Is there a way, preferably a light weight one using Azure resources, to accomplish scanning of a file stream after upload but before committing the file to any kind of storage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you currently using Azure VMs or Azure ASP to host your app?

Comment: @CtrlDot--Azure App Service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17919064-antimalware-feature-on-web-apps-app-service), there is no native virus scanning / anti-malware feature on Websites. One way to enable this scenario would be to use either Web Roles in a Cloud Service or Virtual Machines.

Besides, you cannot install simply anti-malware software on Web Apps (unless that software could be deployed with your app, and not require admin-level privileges).

The another way here is using a third part web api, like [this](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/).

After user upload files, firstly post the file to the API to scan the file, if the result is success, then you continue upload the file to the storage.